# How to wrap long if statements in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In pinescript is it possible to wrap a long if statement such that each condition is on a new line?

Example:

```
if condition_1 or condition_2 or condition_3
    //do something
```

Desired format:

```
if condition_1 or 
 condition_2 or 
 condition_3
    //do something
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If it wraps to the next line then the continuation of the statement must begin with one or several (different from multiple of 4) spaces.

[Here are some examples](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html)

For example with `if` condition:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

condition1 = barstate.islast
condition2 = true

if condition1 and 
 condition2     // one space only
    label.new(bar_index, low, text="Hello, world!", style=label.style_circle)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with if statements.

Comment: Works with `if` statements also. I've edited my answer and added an example with an `if` statement. Just use 1 space